# Paste multiple formatted cells into excel 12

Tags: .net, winforms, excel, clipboard

I use a custom data grid to store some formatted text in the cells, which in turn uses winforms builtin rtf editor to show and store data in the cells. I want to exchange data with excel using the windows clipboard. However, I cannot make excel accept RTF markup. Instead of formatted data, I get all the text along with the RTF markups. Please note that I want to copy/paste multiple cells.

Is there a way to give a hint to excel 12 to make it use the markup?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to generate a [Data Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format) compatible clipboard entry when to push your grid into the clipboard.

Excel pushs a lot of variants of a given grid portion copied into the clipboard. Behave the same way and Excel will be able to read your clipboard content as a table.

You may also look at what formats Excel generates in the clipboard with a clipboard viewer like [this one](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/).